# why xargs cannot receive argument

Tags: xargs

I have some sql files and want to dump to my local db, first I used this shell command , but it does not work

```
ls *.sql|xargs -i mysql -uroot -p123456 foo < {}
zsh: no such file or directory: {}
```

but below could work

```
echo hello | xargs -i echo {} world
hello world
```

so why the first command does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirections are handled by the shell before any commands are run. If you want `xargs` to handle a redirection, you need to run a subshell.

```
ls *.sql | xargs -i sh -c 'mysql -uroot -p123456 foo < {}'
```

However, you should not be using `ls` to drive scripts. You want

```
for f in *.sql; do
    mysql -uroot -p123456 foo <"$f"
done
```

or quite possibly just

```
cat *.sql | mysql -uroot -p123456 foo
```